# How to initialize instance variables in setup()?

Tags: hadoop

This should be a simple question, but I'm struggling with it.  Everything in my code is working except for initializing the parameter values for "train_rows" and "cols" read in from the Configuration file.

I set up logging to display the values of "train_rows" and "cols" within the setup() method, and the values were correct.  However, when I tried the same thing within the map() method, both values showed 0.  What am I doing wrong?

import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class KNNMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
  private static final Logger sLogger = Logger.getLogger(KNNMapper.class);
  private int[][] train_vals;
  private int[] train_label_vals;
  private int train_rows;
  private int test_rows;
  private int cols;

  @Override
  public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

      train_rows = conf.getInt("rows", -1);
      cols = conf.getInt("columns", -1);

      //just changed this
      //int[][] train_vals = new int[train_rows][cols];
      //int[] train_label_vals = new int[train_rows];

      train_vals = new int[train_rows][cols];
      train_label_vals = new int[train_rows];

      // read train csv, parse, and store into 2d int array
      Scanner myScan;
        try {
            File trainfile = new File("train_sample.csv");
            if (!trainfile.exists()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("train file didn't load");
            }
            myScan = new Scanner(trainfile);

            //Set the delimiter used in file
            myScan.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");

            //Get all tokens and store them in some data structure
            //I am just printing them

            for(int row = 0; row < train_rows; row++) {
                for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                    train_vals[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(myScan.next().toString());
                }
            }

            myScan.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("Error: Train file execution did not work.");
        }

    // read train_labels csv, parse, and store into 2d int array
        try {
            File trainlabels = new File("train_labels.csv");
            if (!trainlabels.exists()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("train labels didn't load");
            }

            myScan = new Scanner(trainlabels);

            //Set the delimiter used in file
            myScan.useDelimiter("[,\r\n]+");

            //Get all tokens and store them in some data structure
            //I am just printing them

            for(int row = 0; row < train_rows; row++) {
                    train_label_vals[row] = Integer.parseInt(myScan.next().toString());
                    if(row < 10) {
                        System.out.println(train_label_vals[row]);
                    }
            }

            myScan.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("Error: Train Labels file not found.");
        }
  }

  @Override
  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // setup() gave us train_vals & train_label_vals.
        // Each line in map() represents a test observation.  We iterate 
        // through every train_val row to find nearest L2 match, then
        // return a key/value pair of <observation #, 

        // convert from Text to String

        System.out.println("I'm in the map!");
        String line = value.toString();
        double distance;
        double best_distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        int col_num;

        int best_digit = -1;
        IntWritable rowId = null;
        int i;
        IntWritable rowNum;
        String[] pixels;

        System.out.println("Number of train rows:" + train_rows);
        System.out.println("Number of columns:" + cols);
        // comma delimited files, split on commas
        // first we find the # of rows

        pixels = line.split(",");
        rowId = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(pixels[0]));
        System.out.println("working on row " + rowId);
        best_distance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

        for (i = 0; i < train_rows; i++) {
            distance = 0.0;

            col_num = 0;

            for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                distance += (Integer.parseInt(pixels[j]) - train_vals[i][j-1])^2;
            }

            if (distance < best_distance) {
                best_distance = distance;
                best_digit = train_label_vals[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("And we're out of the loop baby yeah!");
        context.write(rowId, new IntWritable(best_digit));
        System.out.println("Mapper done!");
  }
}
```

Comment: these lines are showing '0' ? System.out.println("Number of train rows:" + train_rows);
        System.out.println("Number of columns:" + cols);

Comment: are u able to scan the file train_sample.csv . train_sample.csv is located in where ? in hdfs ?

Comment: Yes those lines show 0.  I am able to scan the files within setup(), and they are located in hdfs.  I used DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf); to allow for the shorter name.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt this , assuming you are scanning the file in hdfs.

you used:

import java.io.File; File trainfile = new File("train_sample.csv");

in hadoop this is how we check for a file in hdfs :

try {
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());

```
if (fs.exists(new Path("/user/username/path/of/file/inhdfs"))) {
        System.out.println("File exists");
}

 } catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Comment: That part isn't the problem (see my reply above).  Within setup() the file reads in fine, as do the parameter values.  But those values are not accessible within map() for some reason.  I'll note that I just stuck a second copy of the conf.getInt() statements within map() and the program runs perfectly, it's just inefficient to load it for every map and I assume there's a better way.